# Joint tables in jpa

Tags: java, jpa

I have this query to execute with JPA but it doesn't want to work... However if I try to do it directly on the database query exectuor it works fine. Where's the problem in it please ?

```
    public static void GETGET ()
    {
    String str = "SELECT w FROM Workers w ,Liens l ,Qualifications q WHERE l.woId = w.woId AND l.quId = q.quId AND w.woNuitT > 0";

    javax.persistence.EntityManager entityManager= UtilDAO.getInstance().entityManager;
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery(str);
    try
    {
        List<Workers> ob =query.getResultList();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Whenever my users write bug reports that say "X doesn't work" I wonder why it doesn't ever occur to anyone that how something fails might be a clue to why it failed. But being programmers, surely we know better and described observed and expected behaviour?

Comment: What exception do you get? The query looks ok (I would tidy up the commas between the class names just in case). Are the data types you're using on the join exactly the same? @meriton: "Computer says no"? :D

Comment: Also, your mapping files or annotated entity classes might be relevent. But please keep it short, see also http://sscce.org/.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the SQL query in JPA, use the below code.

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(str);
```

Instead of,

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(str);
```